# Changing the Colors of line in Interaction plot

Tags: r

Any help in changing the theme and colors of the lines of the following graph.  The object 'p' contains all the info.

```r
text = "
ability    edu        sales
    2.1696     1.8571  3717.1243 
     4.0558     1.8571  6030.4851 
     5.9420     1.8571  8343.8458 
     2.1696     3.8233  3796.0685 
     4.0558     3.8233  5795.6345 
     5.9420     3.8233  7795.2006 
     2.1696     5.7894  3875.0127 
     4.0558     5.7894  5560.7840 
     5.9420     5.7894  7246.5554 
"
mod_data = read.table(text = text, header = TRUE)
pacman::p_load(interactions)
fit = lm(sales ~ ability*edu, data = mod_data)
p = interact_plot(fit, pred = "ability", modx = "edu")
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could set your desired colors via the `colors=` argument of `interact_plot` and the `theme` could be set or adjusted as for any other `ggplot`:

```
library(interactions)

interact_plot(fit, pred = "ability", modx = "edu", colors = c("red", "blue", "green")) +
  theme_grey() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]